# Running App crashes and mistake and stack trace are notlonger shown

Tags: android, stack-trace, logcat

After updating Android Studio to 2020.3.1., the stack trace of the crash is no longer shown under "run" (console / logcat). This message is appearing in the console:

I/.b: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned ... but it does not show the stacktrace

Tombstone seems to be a kind of file under the path "data/tombstone" or something like that, as it is said, but nowhere on my disk a tombstone file exists?

first question: where can i watch this stack trace - where is tombstoned?

second question: how can I set: to report the crash in the logs? As it is normal and as it was before updating? and why the stack trace is no longer shown?

for example: setting a wrong index in the program, no index exception stack is shown to report the crash. instead this strange message.